# Why I'm getting Error inflating class fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which contains fragment.

The Activity Looks:

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="keepInTouch.mainScreen.MainActivity">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmnet_main_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_list" />
</LinearLayout>


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
    }
```

The fragment look:
fragment_main_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="keepInTouch.today.MainListFragment">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/mainFragmentListTitle"
        android:background="#e43d3d"
        android:textColor="#371b1b" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvKits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>


public class MainListFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);
    }
```

I'm getting the following error:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class Fragment

I have try to replace 
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
with:
MainActivity extends FragmentActivity

But I got same results.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: you didnt supply a name attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `android:name` attribute in your `fragment`. Do this:

```
<fragment 
        android:id="@+id/fragmnet_main_list" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:name="keepInTouch.today.MainListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_list" />
```